# Instrumenting code for application auditing in MS Azure

Tags: azure

I have been looking for some details about auditing functionality in MS Azure. I have read the details about OS Security Event logging but have been trying to find out how service application developers can instrument their code to generate application specific audit events. I have read the content in a bunch of online blogs and notes but it is not clear how application specific events can be audited. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Official service you may use called Application Insights. Basically, you may integrate its agent into your application and generate any type of the custom event (like a simple event "something happened" or more complex, with a dictionaries, etc, and it will be visible on the portal). It can be implemented for the server monitoring as well and send events from the system.

[Reference #1 - Application Insights API for custom events and metrics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/)

[Reference #2 - Logs, exceptions and custom diagnostics for ASP.NET in Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-search-diagnostic-logs/)